# What is a Kubernetes Manifest?

Tags: kubernetes

I've searched online and most links seem to mention manifests without actually explaining what they are. What are Manifests?

Comment: Manifest is a file (JSON or YAML), containing a description of all the components you want to deploy. Refer the official doc : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's basically a Kubernetes "API object description". A config file can include one or more of these. (i.e. Deployment, ConfigMap, Secret, DaemonSet, etc)

As per [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-manifest):

> Specification of a Kubernetes API object in JSON or YAML format.
>
> A manifest specifies the desired state of an object that Kubernetes will maintain when you apply the manifest. Each configuration file can contain multiple manifests.

And a previous version of the documentation:

> Configuration files - Written in YAML or JSON, these files describe the desired state of your application in terms of Kubernetes API objects. A file can include one or more API object descriptions (manifests).

Comment: can you update the link. The above link is no longer available.

Comment: Updated thanks for pointing out. I can't find what was described initially so I pointed to an updated part of the docs. Docs are in constant flux :-)

Answer (score 9):

When you are going to deploy to kubernetes , or create a kubernetes resources like a pod , replica-set , configmap , secret , deployment , etc , you need to write a file called manifest that describe that object and its attributes either in yaml or json.

Just like you do in:

- puppet manifest
- ansible playbook
- chef recipe

etc

Ofcourse you can create those objects by using just command line , but the recommended way is to write a file so that you can version control it and use it in a repeatable way.