# Kubernetes MutatingWebhookConfiguration Create other objects

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using a `MutatingWebhookConfiguration` in order to inject a sidecar app into my pod. This works fine, but I'd like now to be able to create a new service for this sidecar. Anyway my question is a bit broader: can we from a webhook create other objects or are we limited to mutate only the request object ?

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't have such a mechanism: Mutating Webhooks for an outside object or manifest.

In essence, you can concatenate as many objects/manifests in a [Kubernetes config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-journeys/users/application-developer/foundational/#section-2). So, you could have a manifest that injects the sidecar component together with the creation of a service.  You can separate the manifests using a `---` line, which signals the start of a new [document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788318/2989261) in YAML. Then apply the whole configuration files with:

```
$ kubectl apply -f <config-file>.yaml
```

More background on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132302/2989261).

Comment: But my webhook is hooked to the `apps`and `deployment`types. How can I do this for a whole manifest ?

Comment: I tried to add a document separtor `---` and a new object in the manifest, but  my hook only gets called for the individual objects. Maybe I did not get what you meant.

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. The webhook will only work on one object. Adding another manifest will just create the new object afterward. That's a poor boy's workaround.  There's no real way to mutate a separate object with a mutating admission controller.